# multiples django apps deployment on docker and nginx

Tags: django, nginx, docker-compose

hello i want to deploy two Django apps on Docker and Nginx and Gunicorn with different static volume,i am on local with Kali Linux OS.
this my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:

  appone:
    build: ./appone
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/services/appone/src
      - static_volume:/opt/services/appone/static  # <-- bind the static volume
      - media_volume:/opt/services/appone/media  # <-- bind the media volume
    networks:
      - nginx_network
      - database1_network
    depends_on:
      - database1


  apptwo:
    build: ./apptwo
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/services/apptwo/src
      - static_volume:/opt/services/apptwo/static  # <-- bind the static volume
      - media_volume:/opt/services/apptwo/media  # <-- bind the media volume
    networks:
      - nginx_network
      - database2_network
    depends_on:
      - database2

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13
    ports:
      - 8000:80
      - 8001:80
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - static_volume:/opt/services/appone/static  # <-- bind the static volume
      - media_volume:/opt/services/appone/media  # <-- bind the media volume
      - static2_volume:/opt/services/apptwo/static  # <-- bind the static volume
      - media2_volume:/opt/services/apptwo/media
    depends_on:
      - appone
      - apptwo
    networks:
      - nginx_network

  database1:
    image: postgres:10
    env_file:
      - config/db/env
    networks:
      - database1_network
    volumes:
      - database1_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  database2:
    image: postgres:10
    ports:
    - "5433:5432"
    env_file:
      - config/db/env2
    networks:
      - database2_network
    volumes:
      - database2_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data

networks:
  nginx_network:
    driver: bridge
  database1_network:
    driver: bridge
  database2_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  database1_volume:
  database2_volume:
  static_volume:  # <-- declare the static volume
  media_volume:  # <-- declare the media volume
  static2_volume:  # <-- declare the static volume
  media2_volume:
```

and my nginx conf is like that:

```
upstream django_server {
    server appone:8000;
    server apptwo:8001;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # everything is passed to Gunicorn
        proxy_pass http://django_server;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /opt/services/appone/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /opt/services/appone/media/;
    }
}
```

> the docker compose build command works but i don't know how to configure the static folder of the twos django applications to make them works independently.Please Help me!

Comment: You should create a separate `server` for each application in your nginx config. Having both apps in your `upstream` means that requests for one site may be incorrectly sent to the wrong app?

Comment: Okay,i know it's the idea,but i don't know how to do it in practice.give me more details please.

Answer (score 0):

You should define separate app.conf files. Keeps things neater.

app_0.conf
# declare upstream
upstream app_0 {
server app_0_web:8000;
}

```
# define main server
server{
    server_name domain.com;
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app_0;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location ^~ /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /app_0/static/;  #as defined in the docker-compose.yml for app_0 service
    }

    location ^~ /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /app_0/media/; #as defined in the docker-compose.yml for app_0 service
    }
}
```

app_1.conf

```
# declare upstream
upstream app_1 {
    server app_1_web:8000;
}

# define main server
server{
    server_name domain.com;
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app_1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location ^~ /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /app_1/static/;  #as defined in the docker-compose.yml for app_1 service
    }

    location ^~ /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /app_1/media/; #as defined in the docker-compose.yml for app_1 service
    }
}
```